# gvim configuration does not work like it should

Tags: configuration, vim, gvim

I have a little problem with my vim config.

This what I got in my `home/user/.gvimrc`

```
syntax enable "Enable syntax hl


colorscheme peaksea

set background=dark

set gfn=Inconsolata:h11

set nonu



set history=1000

set scrolloff=3

set number " turn on line numbers

" Save a global session file on session close
nmap SQ <ESC>:mksession! ~/.vim/session/Session.vim<CR>:wqa<CR>

function! RestoreSession()
  if argc() == 0 "vim called without arguments
    execute 'source ~/.vim/session/Session.vim'
  end
endfunction
autocmd VimEnter * call RestoreSession()
```

The colorsheme work, but the font has way to much spacing. Every sentence is twice as long. I installed the `Inconsolata` font and I have the same config on my windows 7 box and it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

You're using the wrong format for the `'guifont'` setting.  The format `FontName:h10` works for Windows, but not *nix.  Instead, use `:set gfn=*` to bring up the font dialog to choose your font and size.  Then you can check the correct format for your current OS.  Or you can read `:help 'gfn'`.